# Testing Codeception on Gitlab CI with Selenium service

Tags: selenium, codeception, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to setup selenium standalone chrome service to test my Codeception suit.

I run chrome standalone as a service:

```
services:
  - mysql:latest
  - selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
```

And then I setup the connections for my Codeception test uses WebDriver with an [extension for WordPress](https://github.com/lucatume/wp-browser):

```
WPWebDriver:
   url: 'http://localhost'
   host: 'selenium__standalone-chrome'
   browser: chrome
   port: 4444
   restart: true
   wait: 2
   adminUsername: admin
   adminPassword: 1234
   adminUrl: /wp-admin
```

All other tests run well but when it comes to the suite where I use Selenium it refuses to connect:

```
Time: 7.55 seconds, Memory: 16.00MB

There was 1 failure:

---------
1) SampleTestCept: Test if wp is working in selenium
 Test  tests/php/acceptance/SampleTestCept.php
 Step  See "Just another WordPress site"
 Fail  Failed asserting that  on page /
--> This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
Reload
DETAILS
--> contains "this site can't be reached".

Scenario Steps:

 2. $I->see("This site can't be reached") at tests/php/acceptance/SampleTestCept.php:6
 1. $I->amOnPage("/") at tests/php/acceptance/SampleTestCept.php:4
```

Any ideas of what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use environment variable HOSTNAME, to find gitlab runner actual hostname.

Answer (score 1):

I worked around this by replacing 'localhost' in your webdriver config by the ip-address of the gitlab runner. You might want to check out my blog post about [running codeception tests on gitlab-ci](https://blog.johanv.org/posts/gitlab-ci-codeception-and-selenium-web-tests/).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the issue is that you are using `http://localhost` url and running selenium server on separate host.

Selenium tries to connect to port 80 of its own, not of the machine which is running tests.

Comment: By now I figured out that this is actually the problem. But I've tried using the hostname of my image `'tutum__wordpress'`, did not work.

I've tried to search for the hostname of the base container but I've found nothing, in [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/README.html) they do not provide any variable with it.